# Import date from a txt SAS

Tags: import, sas

Currently I'm trying to import a .txt file to SAS, but I have one problem. The .txt I recieve has a columnthat looks this way

.......;2015/09/01 09:49;....

I need to import it as a date value not as a string. I've tryed many formats but none of them works correctly.

```
data aux;
infile  "&LIBIN/&fichero" delimiter = ';'  MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767;

format fecha_mov .... ;
informat fecha_mov ....;
input
fecha_mov ;
run;
```

Thanks for the help in advanced,

Antonio,

Comment: If you've tried "many informats", you should list them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The informat anydtdtm. works for me.
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002605552.htm

```
data want;
infile cards dsd dlm=',';
informat dt anydtdtm.;
format dt datetime21.;
input dt;
cards;
2015/09/01 09:49
2015/09/01 08:49
2015/09/02 09:49
2015/09/05 09:49
;
run;

proc print; 
run;
```

Comment: Pefect thanks¡ Had no idea of the existence of this format¡

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more specific informat- that way if the source file ever changes unexpectedly, you remove the risk of the `anydtdtm.` format interpreting it incorrectly. If you use the `:` format modifier, you can ignore the time part and just use `yymmdd10.`:

```
data want;
infile cards dsd dlm=',';
input dt :yymmdd10. another_var $5.;
format dt yymmdd10.;
cards;
2015/09/01 09:49,dummy
2015/09/01 08:49,dummy
2015/09/02 09:49,dummy
2015/09/05 09:49,dummy
;
run;

proc print; 
run;
```

N.B. if you don't use a `:` then SAS will not move the line pointer to the next delimiter character before starting to read in the next variable.